# Sense induced current in coil near AC mains 240 volt

Tags: current, transformer, coil, inductance

My heater has no indicator to let me know that its switched on and using power. Sometimes I forget that its switched on. If I (safely) put a coil near one of the conductors (away from the other conductor. Perhaps inside an insulated box) I think I could sense whether power is being used. This heater is switched on by an electronic circuit and not an on/off switch. Using the same principle as in an AC clamp ampere meter I want to produce about 5 volts in my coil which will be enough to power a red led (or interface to microcontroller) showing me that the heater is on and using power. How might I design a suitable coil i.e.  where to place it, how many turns etc? If I cant get 5 volts easily then how much would be easily achievable? I think this type of device is called a current transformer and easily available but I'd rather construct and learn. (I am a qualified electronics technician ,C&G 224, who knows how to avoid killing himself)

Comment: I think you mean induced voltage rather than induced current. Induction relates to voltages as per Michael Faraday. You'll need to provide more information to get a decent answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that doesn't work, because the two wires are in the same cable. The magnetic field from one wire is cancelled by the field from the other wire.

Instead, buy an [Automatic Vacuum Switch for Power Tools](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07YK9VBQK), plug the heater into it, and plug a lamp in the other outlet. When the heater is on, the lamp lights up.

Comment: I'm going to rewrite the question as it's not very clear.